# Dual of a finitely generated projective module is again finitely generated and projective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $M$ be a module over the commutative ring $k$. Put $M^* = \operatorname{Hom}_k(M,k)$.

If $M$ is finitely generated and projective, is the same true for $M^*$?

I tried using a finite dual base to construct a finite dual base for $M^*$ but it does not work out. How can I show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $M \oplus N \cong k^n$, then $M^* \oplus N^* \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M \oplus N,k) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(k^n,k)=k^n$. Thus $M^*$ is projective. As we have a surjection $k^n \to M^*$, $M^*$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Why is the isomorphism with the Hom true?

Comment: Ah yes I believe this holds when M and N are finitely generated projective and this is the case here?

Comment: @user839372 it is always true for all modules $M,N$ and $L$ that $\mathrm{Hom}(M \oplus N,L) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M,L) \oplus \mathrm{Hom}(N,L)$

Comment: Ah yes, ok! Thanks!

Comment: Just because $\text{Hom}(-, k)$ is a functor I suppose!